# swap fields in file names

Tags: filenames, rename

How can I do the following change in file names. I suppose this is possible with `rename`, but I do not know how.

```
A_B_C.pdf
```

to

```
C_A_B.pdf
```

`A`, `B` and `C` are different words in my file names, like `Complete_Works_Plato.pdf`, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rename -n 's/([^_]*_[^_]*)_([^_]*).pdf/$2_$1.pdf/' *
```

- `[^_]*` Any number of non-underscores.
- `( )` Captures a group. The 1st pair is reproduced by `$1` and the 2nd pair by `$2`.

Remove the `-n` if you are satisfied with the output.

A similar approach with shell script:

```
for file in *.pdf; do
    f12=${file%_*}
    f3=${file##*_}
    f3=${f3%.pdf}
    mv -- "$file" "${f3}_${f12}.pdf"
done
```

In [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) you find the meaning of `%` and `##`.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks too for the info for doing a shell script.

Comment: @fich You are welcome. I provided the shell script because some systems may lack `rename`.